# Strong parameters issues, cannot assign new method.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a new method under strong params in rails4 specifically to concat my `'first_name'` & `'last_name'` and redefine them as `'full_name'` ... This was easy with `attr_accessible` but now I'm a bit lost.

Can anyone give me a run through of how to make this change so that I can call `'full_name'` in future to give `first_name` and `last_name` combined?

thanks!

Comment: define a `full_name` method in your model. This has nothing to do with strong parameters (or `attr_accessible`).

Answer (score 2):

in user.rb model

```
def full_name
  (first_name + " " + last_name).strip
end
```

then using object of user let's say `@user` when you'll call this method it will return the full name of user, for example

```
@user.full_name
```

Comment: right idea, but you'll end up with names without a space in between.

Comment: Careful if `last_name` is blank you'll endup with a trailing whitespace

Comment: So, pierre, first_name + (first_name.blank? ? "" : " ") + last_name

Comment: Just do `(first_name + " " + last_name).strip`

Comment: more clean `[first_name, last_name].join(' ').strip`

Answer (score 1):

In your `User` Model,you can do like this

```
def full_name
 if first_name.present? && last_name.present?
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}" 
  end
 end
```

**OR**

```
def full_name

return first_name.to_s.strip + ' ' + last_name.to_s.strip

end
```

and you can call it with an instance like `@user.full_name`,which displays the user's `full_name`.

Answer (score 0):

**Strong Params**

[`Strong Params`](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) is just about passing particular elements from the [params hash](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters) to your model (you'd only use this if you wanted to pass the `full_name` attribute through to your model)

Strong params replaced `attr_accessible` in Rails 4; basically allows you to define which params you'll pass through the controller to the model. Has nothing to do with which data has been sent; only that you're permitting it or not

You'd use strong params if you wanted to *set* the `full_name` attribute, as below:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
Class UsersController < ApplicationController
    private
    def strong_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:full_name)
    end
end
```

---

**Attributes**

You'd make an instance method in your model to handle the other two attributes

You must remember that Rails just takes data objects & creates a series of instance methods to make them accessible as "attributes". If you wanted to display `full_name`, you'll be able to define a public instance method in your model to display the data:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   def full_name
      first_name + " " + last_name
   end
end
```

Hopefully this explains it for you. You'll benefit from using `RSB`'s answer